# Linear regression with time-varying parameters

Tags: regression, time-series, stata, kalman-filter, dynamic-regression

I am attempting to estimate the following model in Stata (the only statistics package I'm familiar with):

$$
Y_{t}=\alpha_{t} + \beta_{t}X_{t}+\varepsilon_{t} 
$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are series and $\alpha_{t}$ and $\beta_{t}$ are time-varying parameters defined in state equations:
$$
\alpha_{t}=\alpha_{t-1}+\eta_{1t}
\\
\beta_{t}=\beta_{t-1}+\eta_{2t}
$$
which are assumed to follow a random walk.  $\varepsilon$, $\eta_{1t}$, $\eta_{2t}$ are assumed to be gaussian independent white noise.

I am interested in finding the value of $\beta$ over time.  The paper from which I am working suggests estimation by the Kalman filter.

I have attempted to understand and implement the `sspace` function here, but I believe it is incapable of handling the time variation.

Is any of this achievable in Stata 11?

Comment: I don't quite follow your terminology.  When you say "i and j are observations..." do you mean you have two series $X_{1,t}$ and $X_{2,t}$, in which case you would be better off dropping the i and j and going with $X_{1,t}$ and $X_{2,t}$ or even $X_t$ and $Y_t$.  Or does it mean something else?

Comment: Sorry - I mean there are two series.  Your interpretation is correct.  I have edited the question for clarity.   I'm copying exactly the syntax of the paper I'm using and didn't explain it clearly enough.  I suppose the reason they used this particular notation is because it's the same variable across a panel.

Comment: It's a state space model and so KF estimation would be an obvious tool. I don't know Stata though. If you write the model in terms of differences and simplify, it looks like you can at least estimate $\beta_{t-1}$ with a regression model, though you have to worry about the induced correlation structure in the error term.

Comment: @Glen_b thanks for your input.  The more I investigate the more I think this has to be done in R or MATLAB because of the time variation.